# Browser does not show image (Angular)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, image

In the header component, I needed to add a logo image, so I wrote the following in HTML:

header-component.html

```
<div class="col-md-4 text-left">
  <a routerLink="/">
      <img id="logo" src="../images/header/Logo.png"
        alt="logo"/>
  </a>
</div>
```

But browser can not see the logo, it just shows the default picture image.
I checked it with the system administrator, there are no network problems.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Try adding the image's directory path in angular.json's assets array and then use the image name just like 'assets/images-name.png'

Comment: try to find real link where the logo is working, and check the real url

Comment: Do you have any error in console? Have you added in the `assets` array in your `angular.json` file the path to that image's folder?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi Yes, assets are added in angular.json. I have an error "GET http://localhost:4200/images/header/Linkedin.png 404 (Not Found)"

Answer (score 0):

To make file publicly available in angular you have to place it it assets folder.
Also bear in mind that in Angular projects, you don't have to add the relative to assets folder. In your case "assets/images/header/Logo.png" will be enough.

---

You can relocate your assets folder in angular.json if needed

```
"assets": [
    "src/assets"
 ],
```

Comment: I tried already, but it does not work. path is 100% right

Comment: Then try moving the image folder into assets folder.  Since angular gives public access to this folder.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not works

Comment: Once you move image inside assets folder, you will have to update the image path just like 'assets/images-name.png'. Did you update the img tag's src path?

Comment: @Krishna Yes, I updated

Comment: Treat assets folder as if it was in app folder. ( Do one less of "../" )

Comment: @MaxTuzenko Oh, It worked with this path "assets/header/Logo.png". Thanks a lot, Have a nice day!

Comment: Please Accept/Upvote my answer if it resolved your issue or comment if you want me to edit it. Have a good one!

Answer (score 0):

Does not work because your own resource providers has to be included in `angular.json`, `assets` is included by default, why are you separating `images` from `assets`? Just create images folder inside assets and call it like `assets/images/logo.png`